# Is $E:= \{e_k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ a weakly compact subset of $l^{\infty} (\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Define $e_k : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
e_k (n) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1, & \quad k = n \\
            0, & \quad k \neq n
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Is $E:= \{e_k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ a weakly compact subset of $l^{\infty} (\mathbb{N})$? Prove.

---

My proof is as follows:

$E$ is a closed subset of $\text{Ball } l^{\infty}$, thus, we only need to check if if $\text{Ball } l^{\infty}$ were weakly compact.

According to Kakutani's Theorem, $\text{Ball } l^{\infty}$ is weakly compact if and only if $l^{\infty}$ were reflexive. But since $l^{\infty}$ is not reflexive, then $E$ is not weakly compact.

Comment: That doesn't work, a subset of a non-compact set may still be compact. So from the non-weakly-compactness of the unit ball, you can't conclude that $E$ isn't weakly compact.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Do you have a clue as to how I can show that $E$ is not weakly compact?

Comment: Sure. Can you find a weakly open set that contains $e_m$, but no other $e_k$?

Comment: Alternatively, if $E$ were weakly compact, it would be weak$^{\ast}$-ly compact. And hence weak$^{\ast}$-closed.

Comment: @HarryEvans Try the linear maps that take an element of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ and return the $n$th entry in the sequence. Show they are linear and bounded. These maps will separate each point of $E$ from the others. You can use them to find an infinite weakly open cover with no proper subcover.